# I can't run commands from .composer/vendor/bin

Tags: php, composer-php, lumen

I made

> echo 'export PATH="$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin"' >> ~/.zshrc

then

> source ~/.zshrc

In my $PATH I have:
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:~/.composer/vendor/bin

When I try run command

> lumen

it doesn't work, but when i do

> ~/.composer/vendor/bin/lumen

it works.

Maybe someone could help me.
Thanks:)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! First of all, consider reading the [the guide about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow is a programming Q&A community. Since your question is related more to Ubuntu than PHP, this question should go on [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com).

Comment: @Victor I consider you read [the guides](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again: *"software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"* This question exactly fits in this description. Furtermore, when a question is on the line between SO and SU, the policy is to keep the original location. Also, this in no way is bound to Ubuntu...

Answer (score 2):

Eventually I found solution. I used $HOME instead of tilda (~):

> echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"' >> ~/.zshrc

It works :)

Comment: Mark your answer as the solution.